# Operator Norm of the Pullback

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $U,V$ be normed vector spaces. Let $\phi: U \to V$ be bounded and linear. Let the (continuous) pullback of $\phi$ be
$$\phi^\ast : V^\ast \to U^\ast$$
$$\phi^\ast(f) = f \circ \phi$$
which is linear. I am trying to compute $\|\phi^\ast\|$, and I have guessed that it is equal to $\| \phi\|$. I have been able to show that
$$\| \phi^\ast\| \le \|\phi\|$$
And that equality holds if $\| \phi\| \le 1$, but have been unable to show this for $\|\phi\| > 1$. One attempt was the following:

$$\| \phi^\ast\| = \sup ( \sup_{\|u\| = 1} |f(\phi(u))| : \sup_{\|v\|=1} |f(v)| = 1)$$
And then note that
$$\sup_{\|u\| = 1} = \|\phi\|\sup_{\|u\| = 1} \left|f\left(\frac{ \phi(u)}{\|\phi(u)\|} \right) \right|$$
Which reduces the problem to showing
$$\sup_{\|u\| = 1} \left|f\left(\frac{ \phi(u)}{\|\phi(u)\|} \right)\right|  = \|f\| = 1$$
But I am not sure that this is true. I am not sure what to try next. Perhaps I need the Hahn-Banach theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By what you have proved it follows that $\|\phi^{**}\| \leq \|\phi^{*}\|$. [Replace $\phi$ by $\phi^{*}$ in the inequality you got].  Now $\phi^{**}$ is an extension of $\phi$ (when you identify $U$ as  a subspace of $U^{**}$ and $V$ as  a subspace of $V^{**}$). This implies that $\|\phi\| \leq  \|\phi^{**}\|$ so we get $\|\phi\| \leq \|\phi^{*}\|$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need the Hahn-Banach theorem, in principle: Without Hahn-Banach it is unprovable (in ZF with dependent choices) that the dual space of $U=\ell_\infty/c_0$ is nonzero. Hence, it is unprovable in ZF+DC even for the identity map $\phi\colon U\to U=V$ that the adjoint operator $\phi^*$ is nonzero.

In Kavi's reply Hahn-Banach is used to show that $V$ can be identified as a subspace of $V^{**}$.

A more direct proof is almost what you did:
Hahn-Banach implies that for every $v\in V$ there is $f\in V^*$ with
$\|f\|=1$ such that $|f(v)|=\|v\|$. Now given $u\in U$ with $\|u\|=1$,
apply this observation with $v=\phi(u)$ to obtain
$\|\phi^*\|\ge|\phi^*(f)(u)|=|\phi(u)|$.